# Regex to get text from html tags (nested) - Java

Tags: java, regex

Using regex, I want to be able to get the text between multiple html tags. 
Here HTML is just for representation of input, I am not worried about HTML tags, just want to retrieve the content in the HTML tags(between both correct open and close tags).
For instance, the following:

Required Input:

```html
<h1>Text 1</h1>
<h1><h2>Text 2</h2></h1>
<h1><h2>Text 3</h2>Xtra</h1>
<h1>Text 4<h1>extra</h1515></h1>
<h1><h1></h1></h1>
```

Required Output:

```
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
None
None
```

Output Obtained:

```html
Text 1
Text 2
Text 3
Text 4<h1>extra</h1515>
<h1></h1>
```

Regex I tried:

```
"<([\\S ]+)>([\\S ]+)</\\1>"
```

I am not getting the expected result.

My java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution{
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
      while(testCases>0){
         String line = in.nextLine();
         String tmp = line;
          Pattern r = Pattern.compile("<([\\S ]+)>([\\S ]+)</\\1>", Pattern.MULTILINE);
         Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
         while(m.find()){
             line = line.replaceAll(line, m.group(2));
             m = r.matcher(line);
         }
         if(line != tmp)
             System.out.println(line);
          else
              System.out.println("None");
         testCases--;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You [shouldn't use regex to parse html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2398375)

Comment: Mandatory info: [Can you provide some examples of why it is hard to parse XML and HTML with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg). Have you tried using parser?

Comment: What output are you having? What is your current code?

Comment: Welcome to the real world.  HTML is not a regular language, you cannot expect to parse it using regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments that way lies nothing but pain. For what your attempting to do you would be far better off walking the DOM (Document Object Model) with something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)